# What chords should I use in an aggressive orchestral track?

Tags: chords, orchestration

I am trying to learn how to make epic (trailer) music. When I write melodic songs I use mostly major and minor chords and they work great, they give me exactly the sound I want, however those types of chords sound horrible when I use them in aggressive (staccato) epic tracks, so what kind of chords do you think are well suited for such tracks?

Comment: a peek at the score for "Mars, the Bringer of War" by Gustav Holst might be worth the effort

Comment: ...Especially when "Mars" manages to make major chord spam sound aggressive, too.

Comment: tbh, the entirety of Holt's Planet Suite sounds like the inspiration for a considerable number of popular film scores... [cough... John Williams] ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a bit broad, so I'll set up a starter & let other people add their own ideas...

OK, take a simple minor chord, Em.
Voice it E, G, B & play it staccato, repeatedly.
Stodgy as all heck.

Revoice that as G, E - with a big hole in the middle, then drop the B an octave.
Whole different thing, but it's still Em.
Try again, drop that B bass to G below; change your RH voicing to E & B above.

See how much movement you gained & we haven't even changed chord or gone over 3 voices yet.

Comment: True, there's nothing wrong with using simple majors and minors as well as others, it's the voicing and instrumentation, as well as clever timing that do the job.+1.